# Why are steps not being calculated in this function?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, healthkit

I have written a function that is supposed to get the user's steps by using HealthKit. Before I added the code that checks no data was manually added, it worked. After adding the new code (compoundPredicate) it does not calculate steps. Any ideas on what to change to make this work?

Here is the file:

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

extension Date {
    static func mondayAt12AM() -> Date {
        return Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).date(from: Calendar(identifier: .iso8601).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date()))!
    }
}



class HealthStore {
    
    var healthStore: HKHealthStore?
    var query: HKStatisticsCollectionQuery?
    
    init() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            healthStore = HKHealthStore()
            
        }
    }

   


 func calculateSteps(completion: @escaping (HKStatisticsCollection?)-> Void) {
        
        let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
        
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -7, to: Date())
        
        let anchorDate = Date.mondayAt12AM()
        
        let daily = DateComponents(day: 1)
             
        
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
        let compoundPredicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates:
                                    [.init(format: "metadata.%K == NO", HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered), predicate]
                                )
        query = HKStatisticsCollectionQuery(
           quantityType: stepType,
           quantitySamplePredicate: compoundPredicate,
           options: .cumulativeSum,
           anchorDate: anchorDate,
           intervalComponents: daily)
        
        
      
        
        query!.initialResultsHandler = { query, statisticsCollection, error in
            completion(statisticsCollection)
            
        }
        
        if let healthStore = healthStore, let query = self.query {
            healthStore.execute(query)
        }
    }
    
    


func requestAuthorization(completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        let stepType = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)!
        
        guard let healthStore = self.healthStore else { return completion(false) }
        
        healthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: [stepType]) { (success, error) in
            completion(success)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered is simply absent from many or most HealthKit samples, instead of being present with a value of NO.

Try this instead for the predicate `format` parameter: `"metadata.%K != YES"`